# kafka and having multiple consumer groups

Tags: apache-kafka

So i have been trying to get my head around consumer groups and kafka, i understand how a single consumer group work which has multiple consumers each consuming from a partition.

my question is if i have multiple consumer groups, does that mean that each group consumes the same message ie like a fan out. Or does it mean that the topic is further split into partitions. if its the latter, then is it the same as having one consumer group and multiple consumers? whats the difference or reasoning? i understand it has its own offset, which would mean that the messages are not duplicated?

Comment: Matching record content can easily exist in multiple offsets, by the way. That's controlled by the producer, not related to consumer groups / partitions at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the consumer group will consume all messages from all partitions from given topic and two consumers in the same group will never consume the same partition.

This means that if You have 10 partitions and 2 consumers with the same consumer group, in general every consumer will consume all messages from 5 separate partitions and they will never consume the same messages. They will divide all work between each other.

On the other hand, if You have 10 partitions and 2 consumers with different consumer groups, both consumers will consume all 10 partitions from the topic, so overall the messages would be read twice.

Consumer groups are a mechanism to make load splitting as easy as possible, You can just create multiple consumers and assign them a single group and kafka will make sure they don't consume the same messages and thus the load is split. This is also why, when You will have more consumers than partitions, some of the consumers will be idle. If You for some reason want to pass messages to multiple places/applications & You want to make sure they all receive all messages You can simply assign multiple group ids.